# Probability of coin streak at start of sequence

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to work out how to express the probability of getting a streak of either heads or tails at the start of a series of coin tosses, considering those tosses may not be fair. For example, $Y= 3$ if a sequence starts with $HHHTHT....$ or $TTTHHHHT....$.

So far I think that:

$$
P(Y)=P(H)+P(T)
$$

and thus

$$
P(Y=k)=\sum_{i=1}^kP(H=i)P(T=k-i)
$$

but I have got myself confused and don't know where to go now.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear what $Y$ is.  Even its type is unclear: Is it an event or a random variable?  If a random variable then $P[Y=k]$ makes sense ("the probability that $Y$ is equal to $k$") but $P[Y]$ does not ("the probability that $Y$").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $P(H) = p$ and $P(T) = 1-p$.

You are looking for a streak of length $k$. We can classify all streaks of length $k$ into two categories of outcomes. You have the first $k$ flips are heads followed by a tails, or the first $k$ flips are tails followed by a heads. These outcomes have respective disjoint probabilities: $$p^k (1-p)\qquad \text{and} \qquad p(1-p)^k$$

So, the total probability that you start with a streak of length $k$ is given by:

$$p(1-p)\big( p^{k-1}+(1-p)^{k-1} \big)$$

Sorry, don't know why I divided. Probability is multiplicative.

Comment: I updated my answer. It was totally wrong before. I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the update. How do you get from the two disjoint probabilities to the total probability? I thought you calculated the product of $P(A)P(B)$, which would be $p(1-p)(p(1-p))^k$?

Comment: Disjoint probabilities are additive. I factored out $p(1-p)$ from both terms. Multiplication of $P(A)P(B)$ would be given two independent events the probability that event A happens, then event B happens.